# Trying to understand angular cache busting

Tags: angular, build, browser-cache

I am running angular 6.  When building with --prod, the scripts are generated with a name such as main.547a75c48dc342a8e291.js.  I assumed that was a unique name generated each time but it seems to be the same.

How does angular CLI generate this name?  Should I be giving another option to ensure that every time we do a production build it is unique?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`547a75c48dc342a8e291` is a hash. If there are no changes to `main` the hash would be the same. By changing a file included in `main`, the hash will be different, and the cache will bust.

Comment: Thanks @Moshe for the info.